# Is the model definition correct in django

Tags: django, model

I have defined below models in my models.py file.
I am trying to populate Allocation table only for the rows where member is null.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.



class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    DESIGNATION = [
        ('Developer', 'Developer'),
        ('Tester', 'Tester'),
        ('Support', 'Support'),
        ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, choices=DESIGNATION)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Task(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = [
        ( 'Low', 'Low'),
        ('Medium', 'Medium'),
        ('Urgent', 'Urgent'),
        ]

    STATUS = [
        ('Not Started', 'Not Started'),
        ('In Progress', 'In Progress'),
        ('Completed', 'Completed'),
        ]
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    member = models.ForeignKey('Member', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task_status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.name




class Allocation(models.Model):
    
    member = models.ForeignKey('Member', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.OneToOneField('Task', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task.name
```

And here is my view for task allocation

```
def allocate_task(request, pk):

    task_details = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = TaskAllocateForm(instance=task_details)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskAllocateForm(request.POST, instance=task_details)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
```

forms.py:

```
class TaskAllocateForm(ModelForm):  
    class Meta:         
        model = Task         
        fields = ['name', 'member', 'task_status']
```

I am creating new tasks with create method which is working fine.
And I am trying to assign that task to a member from Member table.
But, the form.save() method in the allocate_task view is not reflecting changes in Allocation table

Comment: Can you share the `TaskAllocateForm`?

Comment: ```class TaskAllocateForm(ModelForm):
 class Meta:
  model = Task 
  fields = ['name', 'member', 'task_status']```

Comment: How are you getting the member. Is it member id.

Comment: Yes it is member id

Comment: I have even verified the allocate_task view and form.save() does not return True. So, I came to a conclusion that there might be something wrong with the model?? My update and delete functionalities on Task  table is working fine.